# Print orderly with confirmation form a random list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list that has been previous generated randomly:

```
Car
Boat
Bicycle
House
Apple
```

I'm trying to print them with confirmation, so something like after running will ask me confirm

```
Car
...Y
Boat
...Y
Bicycle
...Y
House
...Y
Apple
...Y
```

`...Y`  represents the user's confirmation.

I have no idea how to do this so any hint is really appreciated.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the user doesn't press Y?

Comment: Maybe a message, but the user will always press Y, sorry for my stupid example, but it is the only thing that I can think off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in "Car Boat Bicycle House Apple".split(" "):
  x = input(f"{item}\n")
  # do something with confirmation x
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll use input() to ask for the answer, then work with it

You can then check the answer:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
list = ["Car", "Boat", "Bicycle", "House", "Apple" ]


for item in list:
    answer = input(item+'?\n') 
    answer = "" + answer
    # converting to lower case makes checking simpler
    answer = answer.lower()
    if (answer == 'y' or answer == 'yes'):
        print("ok")
    else:
        print('No ' +item+  ' for you.')
```